# JPQL Eclipselink - How to join two tables and present items that have no items in the other table

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I try to select all orders that have no bids at all and I got an exception, how do I do it?

this is what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT o, COUNT(b) FROM OrderEntity o LEFT JOIN OrderBidEntity b ON o.id = b.orderId WHERE COUNT(b) = 0 AND o.created < :date ORDER BY o.created ASC

Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT o, COUNT(b) FROM OrderEntity o LEFT JOIN OrderBidEntity b ON o.id = b.orderId WHERE COUNT(b) = 0 AND o.created < :date ORDER BY o.created ASC]. 
[91, 99] The COUNT function is only allowed in the SELECT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY and HAVING clauses.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAcce
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to double check this at the moment, but the error message is quite descriptive. You can try adjusting your query like the following:

```
SELECT o FROM OrderEntity o WHERE (SELECT COUNT(b) FROM OrderBidEntity b WHERE o.id = b.orderId) = 0 AND o.created < :date ORDER BY o.created ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EMPTY check or SIZE instead of COUNT to check for the size of a collection in JPQL.

```
select p from PARENT p where SIZE(p.childCollection) = 0
```

or

```
select p from PARENT p where p.childCollection IS EMPTY
```